# Auth0: `state` does not match on FireFox

Tags: reactjs, firefox, auth0

I have developed a web app using React, using Auth0 for authentication process. I have encountered a problem - every time I successfully login into the web app, when I refresh the page, it would throw the error:

> 'state' does not match

Here is my `Auth.js`:

```
class Auth {
  constructor() {
    this.link = 'https://mywebapp.com'
    this.auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
      domain: <MY_DOMAIN>',
      audience: <AUDIENCE_LINK>,
      clientID: <CLIENT_ID>,
      redirectUri: `${this.link}/callback`,
      responseType: 'token id_token',
      scope: 'openid email profile'
    });

    this.getProfile = this.getProfile.bind(this);
    this.handleAuthentication = this.handleAuthentication.bind(this);
    this.isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticated.bind(this);
    this.signIn = this.signIn.bind(this);
    this.signOut = this.signOut.bind(this);
  }

  getProfile() {
    return this.profile;
  }

  getIdToken() {
    return this.idToken;
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    return new Date().getTime() < this.expiresAt;
  }

  signIn() {
    this.auth0.authorize({}, (err, authResult) => {
      if (err) this.localLogout();
      else {
        this.localLogin(authResult);
        this.accessToken = authResult.accessToken;
      }
    });
  }

  handleAuthentication() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
        if (err) {
          alert(err.errorDescription)
          this.signOut()
          return reject(err);
        }
        if (!authResult || !authResult.idToken) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        this.setSession(authResult);
        resolve();
      });
    })
  }

  setSession(authResult) {
    this.idToken = authResult.idToken;
    this.profile = authResult.idTokenPayload;
    this.expiresAt = authResult.idTokenPayload.exp * 1000;
  }

  signOut() {
    // clear id token, profile, and expiration
    this.auth0.logout({
      returnTo: `${this.link}`,
      clientID: <CLIENT_ID>,
    });
  }

  silentAuth() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.auth0.checkSession({}, (err, authResult) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        this.setSession(authResult);
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my React router setup:

```
const SecureRoute = (props) => {
  const {component: Component, path, checkingSession } = props;
  return (
    <Route path={path} render={() => {
        if (checkingSession) return <div>Loading...</div>
        if (!auth0Client.isAuthenticated()) {
          auth0Client.signIn();
          return <div></div>;
        }

        return <Component />
    }} />
  )
}

class AppStack extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          checkingSession: true
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.location.pathname === '/callback') {
          this.setState({checkingSession:false})
          return;
        }
        try {
          await auth0Client.silentAuth();
          this.forceUpdate();
        } catch (err) {
          if (err.error !== 'login_required') console.log(err.error);
        }
        this.setState({checkingSession:false})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="site-wrap">
                <AppHeader />
                <div className="main">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>} />
                        <SecureRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} checkingSession={this.state.checkingSession}/>
                        <SecureRoute exact path="/project" component={Project} checkingSession={this.state.checkingSession}/>
                        <SecureRoute exact path="/project/:page" component={Project} checkingSession={this.state.checkingSession}/>
                        <SecureRoute exact path="/profile" component={Profile} checkingSession={this.state.checkingSession}/>
                        <SecureRoute exact path="/profile/:page" component={Profile} checkingSession={this.state.checkingSession}/>
                        <Route exact path="/signout" component={Signout}/>
                        <Route exact path='/callback' component={Callback}/>
                        <Route component={NoMatch} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here is the screening of the problem:
https://www.loom.com/share/0c25158cf6b54db288a7c94987f8bb9a

Any reason why I am getting this error when I refresh the page ?

Thanks for any advice !

Comment: And this happens even if you are in private browsing?

Comment: Yes, this happens when I use incognito (private window) in FireFox.

Comment: This can happen when parseHash is called multiple times

Comment: Thank you for the response ! Are there any possible reason caused parseHash to be called multiple times when I refreshed the page ? I have included my react routes setup on the description above !

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue today and this solved it for me:

Make sure you put where you are routing:

example with history:

`history.replace('/home');`

```
this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        this.setSession(authResult);
        history.replace('/home');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this today when I was debugging locally, and the cookie domain was set to the deployed domain name.
Setting the cookie domain to an empty string locally fixed the issue for me.